# How to get field values and do a post in jsp?

Tags: jsp, post

i am working on a simple jsp page, it contain 2 textbox firstname and lastname,and a ok button, when textbox is filled and button is clicked, I need to get values of firstname and lastname and post to url http://mydomain/firstname/lastname, how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the form submit to a `Servlet` which sends a **redirect** to the particular URL. E.g. in JSP:

```
<form action="servletURL" method="post">
    <input name="firstname">
    <input name="lastname">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

With the following in `doPost()` method of a servlet mapped on `url-pattern` of `/servletURL`:

```
String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
response.sendRedirect(firstname + "/" + lastname);
```

This will end up in the desired URL.

Comment: I was doing the wrong thing before, I forgot to name the fields. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think following code can help you in implementing what you want.

```
var firstName = document.getElementById("id of firstname textbox ").value;

 var lastName =document.getElementById("id of secondname textbox ").value;

 http://yourURL?fn=firstName&ln=lastName
```